# Create an Object based on an existing object

Tags: javascript, prototype

I'm new to Prototypal inheritance and I've been stuck in an easy task

I have something like this:

```
var test1 = {
       clear : function () { 
         alert('hey');
       } 

 }

 var test2 = {
       varB : 2

 }
```

I would like to test2 extend from test1. 
Can anyone give me a direction? Should I still  use Object.create, or maybe a function + call method?
Im a bit confused here.

Every example that i found are based on extending and then setting attributes, methods, etc.. But my object is already declared here.

Thanks!

Comment: http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/06/07/understanding-javascript-prototypes/

Answer (score 1):

In modern browsers, you can use [`Object.setPrototypeOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf):

```
Object.setPrototypeOf(test2, test1);
```

There is currently no other (official) way to change the prototype of an *existing* object.

If you are just creating a simple object, you can use [`Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create):

```
var test2 = Object.create(test1);
test2.varB = 2; // or Object.assign(test2, {varB: 2});
```

If you don't actually need inheritance, merging the objects with [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) would be an option:

```
Object.assign(test2, test1);
```

This simply copies the properties from `test1` to `test2`. Unlike with inheritance, changes to `test1` don't impact `test2`.

---

For more information, I suggest to have a look at

- [MDN - Working with Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)
- [MDN - Introduction to Object-Oriented JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript)
- [MDN - Inheritance and the prototype chain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain)

Answer (score 0):

A very basic approach would be

```
test2.__proto__ = Object.create(test1)
```

So you will have `clear` function available in `test2` object.

Comment: [MDN Object.prototype.__proto__](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto) :`[...]The __proto__ property is deprecated and should not be used.[...]`

Answer (score 0):

Your can use `prototype` to do inheritance. But it just one of some inherit ways in javascript.

```
function test1() {}
test1.prototype.clear = function () {
    alert('hey');
}

function test2() {}
test2.prototype = new test1();
test2.prototype.varB = 2;

var test2Instance = new test2();
```

And search more javasrcipt inheritance methods with google by yourself.